# How to Have CSS Content Preview in Finder?

Tags: finder

<sub>Running Lion 10.7.4</sub>

---

The `.php` and `.txt` extension have a preview of the content in Finder.

[image: php]

---

But not the `.css`.

[image: css]

---

Is there a `sudo` magic for enabling this?

Answer (score 1):

This the icon generation is dependant on the associated app for that file type, so associating .css files to TextEdit might get them to be treated as plain text in the icons. It's worth a shot, I guess.

Comment: Nope, it just displays a *blank document* icon. By any chance, what does it displays in yours?

Comment: Forgot to mention, even if this worked, wouldn't be a solution as I want to keep TextMate as the default editor... Could this be a TM issue?